# Want t use Exception Handling Block for Enterprise Library 6.0. Can anyone tell me all necessary step or it is same as in EL 4.0

Tags: exception, enterprise-library-6

I have got some example regarding Enterprise Library 4.0 so i have started to develop exception handling blocks same as in 4.0 but I am not getting exception handling. Can anyone say about all necessary steps to use Enterprise Library for Exception Handling Block.